# Do angels speak to the Jewish people today?

Tags: malach-angel

The torah talks about people encountering angels -- celestial creations by Hashem like Gavriel and others.  (For example, Avraham, Yaakov, and Moshe encounter these beings.)  And in the Talmud and Kabbala there are other commonly known names of angels like Uriel, Reziel, Metatron, and Laila.  What about angels today -- do they speak to the Jewish people today?  Where are the messengers from Hashem? For example, is there a Rabbi out there who says: An Angel came to me and said...?

Comment: @Eagel an interface tip: if you want somebody to see a comment, use an @ followed by the name (you should see an auto-completion).  I only saw these comments because I checked back.  You're specifically asking about rabbis, I notice -- but the people in the torah who had encounters with divine messengers/angels, like Avraham, Yaakov, Moshe, and others, weren't rabbis.  Do you mean to restrict your question like that?

Comment: @Monica Cellio Thank you again.But it`s a hard question to ask,because if I say any jew,off course many jews will say they have seen many angels ,but then some will say they are not jews and maybe say they follow another religion .Then we need to talk about what is a jew .So I say rabbi,because a rabbi is always a jew.

Comment: @Eagel But what is a rabbi?

Comment: @Daniel  I would say a Teacher of the house of Israel.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/74042/can-we-know-if-an-angel-is-present

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JVFXZK6LDb8

Answer (score 5):

Strangely enough, while looking through a book today that I am reviewing for a different question, I saw an answer to your exact question. The book is called Sefer HaGematriot by Rabbi Yehudah HaChassid.

In the second volume, parshat Vayeitzei, 9, it discusses this subject. It explains that specifically with those you enumerate, Avraham, Yaacov and Moshe, the Torah uses a 'Ta'am', a diacritical mark for proper reading, called 'pasek' in connection with the doubling of their names in specific pasukim where G-d and His angels spoke to them.

The mark, pasek, means to pause. Rabbi Yehudah explains that from this mark we are to learn and to know that not a single generation passes where there is not one individual from the Jewish people to whom G-d and His angels speaks just like these individuals.

It doesn't mention the title of Rabbi. That doesn't mean Rabbis would be excluded. Originally, the concept of 'semichah', what bestows the title of Rabbi, was the process of connecting to the blessing and empowerment of Moshe to Yehoshua.

But it isn't limited to Rabbis. Moshe also passed along prophecy. That is a completely different path. And as indicated in the text from Rabbi Yehudah, this list also includes Shmuel the Prophet.

Comment: Very interesting

Comment: @SAH  Angels fall under that domain. They are what is referred to as Maggidim, like the Maggid of the Mishnah that communicated with Rabbi Yosef Karo. Although Ruach HaKodesh ended for the Prophets with the destruction of the 2nd Temple, for the Sages, it didn't end.

Comment: @SAH Ruach HaKodesh and Navuah are different levels of the same thing. The Urim v'Tumim and Bat Kol are also part of it. In regard to the level called Navuah, Rambam had a tradition from his grandfather that Navuah would return at the beginning of the days of Moshiach, meaning during Ikvata d'Mashicha.

Comment: @SAH Depending on context, Ruach HaKodesh can be either a generic term for all levels of prophecy like in the teaching of Rabbi Pinchas ben Yair in Avodah Zarah 20a or it can refer to a specific level in the general category of Ruach HaKodesh like can be found in the commentary of Rabbeinu Bachai on Torah and Sha'ar Ruach HaKodesh of Rabbi Chaim Vital.

Comment: @SAH Regarding Rambam's tradition from his grandfather, the Rebbe says this is reliable. See chapters 4 & 5 here. http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25049&st=&pgnum=80

Comment: @SAH Or if you prefer from Likkutei Sichot http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16065&st=&pgnum=312&hilite=

Answer (score 2):

in shaarei kedusha [intro](http://dafyomireview.com/442)

> "And there are those among them which would swear in angels using the
>   powers in holy names.. they desired lofty levels, close to prophecy,
>   and therefore they put themselves in some danger. And for us, would
>   that it were that we would merit a little Ruach HaKodesh such as a
>   revelation of Eliyahu HaNavi (Elijah the prophet), which many merited
>   to see him as is well known, or for a revelation from the soul of
>   tzadikim, as mentioned many times in the book of tikunim. And not only
>   that but even in our times I have seen holy men who merited all these
>   things. And there are some whose own soul after becoming very, very,
>   pure, reveals itself to him and guides him in all his ways. And all
>   these are close ways, that one can merit **even in our times** if he
>   is worthy. But, however, it requires great training and great
>   experience to stand on the truth, because perhaps it is another spirit
>   that came to him which is not pure.

he says later on that one must hide his levels which is presumably why such people don't talk freely about this stuff.

Comment: How does this answer the question? It does not seem to say anything about angels speaking to people.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Rambam all instances of descriptions of people encountering angles are actually events which only happened within the mind of the person experiencing the events.

Comment: rambam is a minority opinion on this.

Comment: `within the mind of the person experiencing the events`... as a prophetic vision or dream sent by HaShem (*Moreh N'vuchim* 2:36,45). Your phrasing is ambiguous and could wrongly be interpreted as saying that the Rambam holds these visions were hallucinations or mere figments of the person's imagination.

Comment: This seems irrelevant to the question at hand. Whatever medium an angel uses to communicate with man, the question remains of whether this activity is present today.

Comment: @ray Who cares if it is a minority opinion. That does not make it false.