# Can we know if an angel is present?

Tags: malach-angel

All over the Torah we can find angels, but how do we know if and when they're around us?

Is there a Rabbi or some other source that can explain how or if there is an angel in the room?

Comment: Avraham was visited by angels and he thought they were human beings. many other stories in tanach regarding human contact with angels. not clear what you're asking. are you asking regarding angels who dont reveal themselves?

Comment: It should be noted that according to the school of thought of Rambam, angels are not physical, and are thus not in a room...or anywhere else. They are encountered instead, in a prophetic state.

Comment: @ray Some say they have seen light or feel an angel present,maybe there are other ways  then a clear human form ?

Comment: @mevaqesh off course,good thinking.So forget "in the room" .The question is more,can we know if we have angels "around us" (in other ways then this clear human form)

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67366/do-angels-speak-to-the-jewish-people-today#comment262859_67366

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JVFXZK6LDb8